# 16.04 crash on GUI interaction

Tags: boot, usb, 16.04

I'm very new to Linux. The last time I booted ubuntu was from a live CD a decade ago.

Goal: I want to live boot from a USB stick, so I can ensure ubuntu will work on my computer.

If I set it up as a dual boot machine.

**Problem**: it crashes after startup.

**Symptoms**: I created a live boot USB stick with universal linux ufd creator. When booting 16.04 from a USB stick, the GUI freezes (cursor does not respond, desktop remains) immediately after attempting any action that  interacts with the system, such as clicking on the system preferences icon, or opening a command prompt vis ctrl alt T. When I attempt to access the command line via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> after it freezes, I am unable to. However, if I reboot, I can open firefox as long as I do nothing else first. That appears not to freeze.

On reboot (again), I open the command line immediately via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. This also freezes.

On a subsequent reboot, I use the check disk integrity function, pounding <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> until it drops into a text mode from the ubuntu splash screen. It says

`errors exist in two of your files`

I am unable to identify which files, because at the end of the integrity check, any attempt to scroll reboots. I re-download the image and recreate the liveboot usb drive. The symptoms remain consistent.

So I reboot again, and when ubuntu is launched, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> during boot. I now have a login prompt. I enter ubuntu and no password.

I now have a command prompt. What should I do to troubleshoot?

EDIT: after fooling around with info for a while, I exit that and try to poke at my graphics configuration by running

`lshw -c video`

I get a warning that I should have run that program as a super user, then the CLI stops responding and I get a repeated

`NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup -CPU#4 stuck for 22s! [lshw:2649]`

Hardware is a HP zbook G3 with m2000m graphics. Sorry for the very long narrative.

Any help troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Last edit: I know this might not be appropriate for askubuntu, and might instead be more appropriate as a bug report. If that is the case, then I am looking for help gathering enough info to file a decent bug report.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for zbook 15 g3 with m1000m was to set graphics to **discrete device** not **auto**.

https://support.hp.com/lt-en/document/c04070522

Comment: oops. necro, sorry cant erase.

Comment: Necroposting isn't generally frowned upon in Stack Exchange.  You might even earn some badges for doing it, e.g. Revival/Necromancer:  https://askubuntu.com/help/badges

Comment: This isn't a link-only answer in my opinion. user698197, please could you [edit] and clarify where you changed this setting? A screenshot would be lovely if obtainable (not from BIOS I guess!). What you say in your post doesn't seem to relate to the support page particularly... (by the way you can delete your posts (see small link underneath) but answering old questions is a good thing here as mentioned above)